# Keeping classes and table schemas in sync when using an ORM

Tags: c#, sqlite, orm, ormlite-servicestack

I haven't had a lot of experience with ORMs. I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle the adding/removing of properties from a mapped class, ideally in an automatic and generic way.

I'm using ServiceStack.OrmLite and SQLite.

The purpose of the database is a document store. There are no foreign keys/referential integrity concerns.

E.G.

```
public class Foo
{
   public Bar {get; set;}
   public Baz {get; set;}
}
```

Creates the table Foo with the columns Bar, Baz.

In an ideal world the Foo class would never changed so I wouldn't have to worry about this, but in reality it could.

Lets say Foo also needs a Quz property.

```
public class Foo
{
   public Bar {get; set;}
   public Baz {get; set;}
   public Quz {get; set;}
}
```

Reading is fine, Quz just comes back as null, but inserting fails because there is no Quz column. This makes sense.

Lets say that Baz is no longer required.

```
public class Foo
{
   public Bar {get; set;}
   public Quz {get; set;}
}
```

Reading/inserting works fine, however the underlying table would still have the Baz column which is a bit messy.

Given that it is a server app, and won't be restarted often, a couple of things I've considered and dismissed:

- On start, If the Foo table exists, read it in to a temporary store, drop and recreate Foo (meaning that the table would be created with the correct schema) and then reinsert the data. This appears to work fine and does the job of keeping the schema in sync with the class, however it is too slow.
- On start, query the underlying table to gets its column definitions and use reflection to work out what the columns for the Foo class should actually be. Add/Drop columns as necessary. I'm pretty sure I could get this approach to work, but it's more complicated than ideal, and I'm not convinced it is a good idea.